# Child classes not requiring parent constructor

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class, extends

I'm programming in Eclipse and have found something strange...

If I create a class like so:

```
public abstract class Test {
    public Test(Object obj) {}
}
```

Any child class would obviously require the `super()` to be filled in.

Same goes for:

```
public abstract class Test {
    public Test(Object[] obj) {}
}
```

So why does my IDE not complain when I do the following, and not provide a `super()`?

```
public abstract class Test {
    public Test(Object... obj) {}
}
```

And before you say "just run the program, it will fail", I used JUnit and the program ran fine, without providing a constructor in the extending class. My question is, why does this happen?

The child class looks like this:

```
public class Child extends Test {
    // Should throw error.
}
```

Comment: With this method `public Test(Object... obj)` you can have 0 or more params to input, by default if the constructor with 0 param then the `super()` will implicit called. So that you don't have to call it

Comment: @TuyenNguyen Ahhhhhhh! That's brilliant. Do you know if there exists an Annotation to force more than one?

Comment: I don't think that It have. Because the syntax `Object... obj` is using for a generic case so you can pass the param or not, but you want to force it must pass the param then you just need using a `List` instead

Comment: @TuyenNguyen Alright. Thanks alot. You should consider posting this as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: To force the caller to supply at least one parameter: `public Test(Object requiredParam, Object... optionalParams)`

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Ah, thankyou!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this method `public Test(Object... obj)` you can have 0 or more params to input. By default, if the constructor does not explicitly call a parent constructor, then `super()` will implicitly be called. You don't have to call it explicitly because the syntax `Object... obj` is used for the generic case, whether you pass in an argument or not. If you want to force the user to pass in a param, then you just need to declare the argument as a `List` instead.

Comment: Very nice answer. I hope you don't mind my edits. I tried to preserve your meaning but make the language conform to 'murican a bit more.

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist, my typo is bad and need to improve!